# sort structure with respect to its field MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, structure

I have a structure which contains location(-x -y coord.) and type information of points:

```
mystr(1).type = 'type2';
mystr(1).location = [5 7]; % [x y] = [5 7]
mystr(2).type = 'type1';
mystr(2).location = [2 8]; % [x y] = [2 8]
```

I have at least as much as 100 points. I want to sort mystr locations first with respect to -y coordinates, second -x coordinates in ascending orders. Last, I want mystr(1) to show the point which has the lowest locations and its type. Also, I want mystr(end) to show the point which has the highest locations and its type.

My code which sorts locations are below.

```
mystr(1).location = [5 7]; mystr(1).type = 'type2';
mystr(2).location = [2 8]; mystr(2).type = 'type1';
mystr(3).location = [3 9]; mystr(3).type = 'type1';
mystr(4).location = [4 2]; mystr(4).type = 'type2';
allpoints = [];
for i = 1:4
    allpoints = [allpoints; mystr(i).location];
end
[~,in] = sort(allpoints(:,2),1,'ascend');
[r,c] = size(allpoints);
allpoints = mat2cell(allpoints,r,2*ones(1));
allpoints = allpoints{1,1}(in,:)
[~,in] = sort(allpoints(:,1),1,'ascend');
[r,c] = size(allpoints);
allpoints = mat2cell(allpoints,r,2*ones(1));
allpoints = allpoints{1,1}(in,:)
for i = 1:4
    mystr(i).location = allpoints(i,:)
end
```

I could not do the types but locations will be like:

```
mystr(1).location = [2 8];
mystr(2).location = [3 9];
mystr(3).location = [4 2];
mystr(4).location = [5 7];
```

PS: I am also glad if anyone can shorten the sorting part. I think it is unnecessarily long. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your anwer:

```
[~, I] = sortrows(cat(1,mystr(:).location),[2 1]);
mynewstr = mystr(I);
```

Best,

Comment: Way to go! But I think you need `[~, I] = sortrows(cat(1,mystr(:).location),[2 1]);` that is, cat _vertically_ and include `1` as _secondary sorting criterion_

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do with the field ̀`type`. If you just need to get the type after sorting, well, the above code already does it: `mynewstr(1).type` contains the type of the first element after sorting, and `mynewstr(end).type` the type of the last element after sorting.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do sorting and filtering of values, then you may want to consider storing the values in a table.

However, assuming you're stuck with a structure, here is what you can do:

```
%# create n-by-2 array with locations
locations = cat(1,mystr.location);

%# sort ascending, so that x are sorted, and within equal x, y are sorted
[~,sortOrder] = sortrows(locations,[1 2]);

%# rearrange the structure
mystrSorted = mystr(sortOrder)
```

Note that this assumes that `location` is never empty; if that is possible, you need to first replace empty with `[NaN NaN]` to avoid a catastrophic mess-up.

Comment: I think it's `[2 1]`, not `[1 2]`: sort first with respect to _y_, then _x_

Comment: @LuisMendo: That's what the OP claimed he wanted to do, but the result presented suggests differently.